# Protractor test throws 'element invalid state' exception as soon as I add 'expect' assertion

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have  protractor test that passes - UNTIL I add an 'expect' assertion to the end of it. As soon as I do that, I get 'InvalidElementStateError: invalid element state'. I'm aware that protractor is asynchronous, so clearly it is building the queue of promises and for some reason barfs at that assertion - but I have no idea why.

```
describe('compose', function() {

    it('should send a message', function() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.findElement(by.id('compose-link')).click();
        browser.sleep(2000);

        //select recipient     
        var el = element(by.name('input_to'));
        el.click();
        el.sendKeys('a');
        //wait for server to autofill...
        browser.sleep(500);
        el.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);

        //SNIP...
        //keep clicking buttons, filling out fields etc...
        //END SNIP

        //select category
        el = element(by.id('section-3')).element(by.css('.secret'));
        el.sendKeys('cl') 

        el = element(by.id('send-now'));
        el.click();
        //wait for confirmation message
        browser.sleep(1000);

        expect(element(by.id('confirm-sent')).getText()).toEqual('Task Sent!');
    });
});
```

BTW, ignoreSynchronization is set to true because otherwise the browser fails to sync apparently due to the server autofill on some elements. I can turn ignoreSync back off after those fields but it makes no difference - I still need to do browser.sleep everywhere to make the test work, so I just leave it set to true.

Answer (score 0):

If the element is appearing on the click() action of an element then wait until click() function returns the promise and then try checking for the element to be visible using wait() function. Then get the text of the element. Using wait() function is more suitable to use than sleep(). Here's a snippet of that functionality -

```
var ele = element(by.id('confirm-sent');
el.click().then(function(){
    browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ele), 10000)
    .then(function(){
        expect(ele.getText()).toEqual('Task Sent!');
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but alas I still get the same error: invalid element state.

Comment: If your element - 'confirm-sent' is appearing after clicking on a button, then probably you should wait until click action is performed on that element. Updated answer with click() chaining.